# PHP Arrays Defined with Empty Strings

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a strange problem with defining and accessing array values.  The strings I've created return empty.  When I do a var_dump, I see that the array values have the correct string lengths, but result in "".  When I attempt to access the variable, I receive "".  Can someone explain this behavior?

```
//define the case combinations
$cases = array(
    "<CO><VO><CO><VOP>",
    "<VO><CLOSED><VO>",
    "<OPEN><CO><VO>",
    "<CO><VOP><ESCB>",
    "<COP><VO><CO><CVN>",
    "<STVE><ESCB>"
);
```

The var dump:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(17) "" [1]=> string(16) "" [2]=> string(14) "" [3]=> string(15) "" [4]=> string(18) "" [5]=> string(12) "" }
```

A similar problem happens with other arrays:

```
$siteSuffix = array(
"data" => array('com','org','net','edu'),
"probabilities" => array(1,1,1,1), //not actually used
"name" => "siteSuffix"
```

`);`

The array under 'data' prints strings in the same manner.

If the problem is external of this, here is a github link where the rest of the code is: [link](https://github.com/BrandonQDixon/RandomDataGenerator/tree/php)

Comment: Both of the codes are working completely fine for me, the issue might be with something else.

Comment: I'm going to guess that it is some sort of character set issue.  What is the charset of your script?

Comment: I also want to point out that the var_dump is showing that these are not empty strings, when it prints out the string length.

Comment: What externally could cause this?  These are both arrays that are not modified once created.  Here's the small github repo if you want to take a look [link](https://github.com/BrandonQDixon/RandomDataGenerator/tree/php)

Comment: Also, for the other comments, I'm using the default charset (I did not specify).  Also, this does not integrate with any html/css, it is pure PHP.  Lastly, when I compare var_dump examples online, they actually explicitly print the string, as well as the length, whereas mine only prints the length.

Comment: Well, I think in the situation with cases, since the strings look like malformed html tags, that might be the problem.  View the source of the page and see what is actually in there.

Comment: They're not html tags, but they are custom tags that I'm using.  As for the source of the page, the var dump is the only element.

Comment: Did you look at the source of the page?  var_dump spits out html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like because you have `htmlentities` in your actual data (array) `<` and `>` PHP will not interpret these as actual values/strings.

What you can do is convert the characters using `htmlspecialchars()`, for example:

```
$cases = array(
    "<CO><VO><CO><VOP>",
    "<VO><CLOSED><VO>",
    "<OPEN><CO><VO>",
    "<CO><VOP><ESCB>",
    "<COP><VO><CO><CVN>",
    "<STVE><ESCB>"
);

foreach ($cases as $case){
   var_dump(htmlspecialchars($case));
}
```

Output of var_dump:

```
string(41) "<CO><VO><CO><VOP>" string(34) "<VO><CLOSED><VO>" string(32) "<OPEN><CO><VO>" string(33) "<CO><VOP><ESCB>" string(42) "<COP><VO><CO><CVN>" string(24) "<STVE><ESCB>"
```

Comment: Turns out, that's right!  When I use a straight jquery test, I get what I'm expecting!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the angle brackets `<` and `>` to print them in browser you can simply use `echo htmlentities($str)` or `htmlspecialchars($str)`for each array item. 
If you are using php command line, then you don't need such encoding.

Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp